# Port Forwarding Stopped working after I moved

Tags: windows-10

I'm making a node js game and used my router to port forward my IP, ex. `192.168.0.10:1000`. Recently I moved apartments and my game stopped working on other computers that are on different Wi-Fi connections.

I logged into my router today and deleted and remade the virtual ports but nothing changed.

The only way I am testing my game is by making a hot spot from my phone and connecting a separate laptop to that internet; when the laptop connected to the hot spot the link I just get "this site can't be reached" and once I disconnect from the hot spot and it joins the house wifi the game works, as it should with localhost.

How I set it up:

I went to `192.168.0.1` - logged into with the default admin and password, went under "Firewall" and then under "Virtual Servers / Port Forwarding" and then clicked "add". Entered this info

- Description: "Teams"
- Inbound Port: "1000" to "1000"
- Format: "Both"
- Private IP Address: "192.168.0.10"
- Local Port: "1000" to "1000"

and then finally clicked "Add Virtual Server"

How do I fix this?

Comment: Recently when you "moved apartments", what else changed? did your router retain the same internal and external IP addresses?

Comment: to my knowledge, everything about the router and my computer are exactly the same; my IP is the same when I go through "IPconfig" in the console and the link to my router is the same

Comment: Sorry for not being available, but should I try contacting my internet provider?

Comment: The machines that dont work - how are they attempting to connect? Do they come in through the internet, go through your router then hit your server? Or maybe they connect to your internal wireless then hit your server?  It would help to know this. One other thing - we know your router has in internal address of 192.168.0.1 but what is the external address,(on the internet side) , and what should it be?  If your friends are going through the internet to your router, but that external address has changed, then you will have this problem.

Comment: BTW, your router's external address is given to you by your ISP. Often when you move, this external address will get changed. If your friends are still trying to reach the old address they won't get through.  You can get the external address of your router by going to Google and type in "What is my IP?" Let me know how it goes Albert.

Comment: You're a lifesaver! My external address did change, (60.112.42.179 for example)  but now when I try to create a port with that IP address I get 
"192.168.0.1 says Invalid IP address. Invalid network address."

There could have been a setting that might've reset when moving, but I honestly don't know what it could be.

I do find it odd that my old IP was only 1 character different than the router's, but now it's completely different. I appreciate your help so far!

Comment: You dont really want to change port forwarding. the settings you mention above should not have to change. Your friends will have to change their settings(they used to connect to the old address, now they need to connect to the new address) but the information you have listed above is correct. The only change you might need to make is if it asks for the external IP information. If it doesn't require you to input the external IP then entering the info above should be all it needs to work.

Comment: Thank you! It works when they connect with external IP - which I find weird since my old IP used to be the same for external and private

Comment: Glad I could help. Keep an eye on that External IP, sometimes your ISP will just change it on you for no reason.